# Como cambiar la direccion de mi base de datos con Room Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Esta es la forma en que inicializo mi database pero la direccion no me la toma si pongo un path custom.

si solo le pongo clientesDatabase si me detecta pero no puedo buscarla en el dispositivo.

```
synchronized(this) {
                    val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        ClienteDatabase::class.java,
                        "/storage/emulated/0/folder/clientesDatabase"
                    ).build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                    return instance
                }
```

Comment: Hola! Una consulta,  tu pregunta es para cargar la base de datos desde un archivo, cierto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cambiar la direcciòn solo cambia el path, por ejemplo esto cambiarìa la direcciòn al directorio de almacenamiento externo:

```
synchronized(this) {
                    val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        ClienteDatabase::class.java,
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/folder/clientesDatabase"
                    ).build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                    return instance
                }
```

No olvides eliminar la aplicaciòn y volver a subirla.

---

Recuerda tambièn no usar la direcciòn directamente ya que en algunos dispositivos podrìa cambiar la direcciòn y provocarias un error.

"/storage/emulated/0/folder/clientesDatabase"

en lugar de esto usa

```
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/folder/clientesDatabase"
```